# Create Attribute (Dropdown) in products

Tags: magento-1.9

Create Dropdown attribute , if dropdown value is "**yes**" than image(any image) will display in products page and if dropdown value is "**no**" than image will not display.

Comment: First You Get Dropdown Attribute Value Yes and No. And set condition if value Yes than display image else should be blank...  Check Below Link to Get Dropdown Value.http://magentocustom.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-get-dropdown-attribute-value-in.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

please follow the my code to getting exact output..

```
<?php
$productId = 1;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($productId);
$selectedvalue  = $product->getAttributeText('paypal');

$atributeCode = 'paypal';
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product',$atributeCode);
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

        foreach($options as $key => $value){

            if(in_array($selectedvalue,$value)){
                if($selectedvalue=='yes')
                {
                echo "<pre>";
               // print_r($value); //get Product's selected attribute options Values
                //echo(implode($value));
                echo "</pre>";  
                //echo "<div id='some'><img src='image.jpg'></div>";
               echo "<img src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/mktg/logo/bdg_now_accepting_pp_2line_w.png' border='0' alt='Now accepting PayPal'>";
                continue;
                }
            }


        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new attribute under **Store -> Attributes**
- link the newly created attribute to the Attribute Set (Store-Menu)
- in your phtml, get value of Attribute with `$_item->getData('your_attribute_code')`. Example below.

  `<?php if($_item->getData('my_attribute') == 1):
      //do something
  endif; ?>`

Comment: Downvoter: explain what is wrong with this solution and I'll try to edit it.